# Add string at beginning in wx.ListBox

Tags: python, wxpython

I am using wxPython 2.8 and in an application of mine I am using a wx.ListBox to add some strings when a specified event is fired. Each time the event is fired I need to add a string at top position of the wx.ListBox (the other strings will be positioned afterwards).

If I have initially the wx.ListBox with following string:

```
World
```

and the next event stores in the listbox the string "Hello"; the result has to be:

```
Hello
World
```

Is it possible ? I have not found any straightforward way to do it.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just use `InsertItems(list,pos)` where `pos` is 0 - the added items will be inserted at whatever position is declared. i.e.

```
import wx

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        initial_items = ['A reasonably long item that should cause a scrollbar to appear xxxxxx', 'another line', 'and another']
        self.listbox = wx.ListBox(self, style=wx.LB_HSCROLL)
        self.listbox.InsertItems(initial_items, 0)
        self.AddBtn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Add Item")
        self.AddBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnAdd)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.listbox, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(self.AddBtn, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnAdd(self,evt):
        self.listbox.InsertItems(['Hello World'], 0) #add at position zero

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "ListBox", size=(400, 400))

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_sizer.Add(MainPanel(self), 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(main_sizer)

        self.Layout()
        self.Center()
        self.Show(True)


app = wx.App()
mw = MainWindow()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]